# outerjoins and aliases confuse the FROM statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to join to multiple tables included in a query.  Some of these joins will be aliased.  For example:

```
c_alias = aliased( C )
q = db.session.query( A, B, C ).join( A.some_things ).outerjoin(
    c_alias, and_(
        c_alias.b_id == B.id,
        c_alias.d_id == 1
    )
)
```

I would expect this to generate SQL like:

```
SELECT
    a.id, b.id, c.id, ...
FROM
    a, b, c
    LEFT JOIN things ON things.a_id = a.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS c_alias ON c_alias.b_id = b.id AND c_alias.d_id = 1
```

However, instead, the `b` and `c` tables are dropped and I get something like:

```
SELECT
    a.id, b.id, c.id, ...
FROM
    a, c
    LEFT JOIN things ON things.a_id = a.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS c_alias ON c_alias.b_id = b.id AND c_alias.d_id = 1
```

which of course throws an error as table `b` is selected from but is never queried.  `A.some_things` is eagerly loaded by default (via `lazy = 'joined'` in the orm), in this case.

**Workaround:**

A join can be added with a condition set to identity that will artificially query the desired table.  In this example:

```
q = db.session.query( A, B, C ).join( B, B.id == B.id ).join( C, C.id == C.id )\
    .join( A.some_things ).outerjoin(
        c_alias, and_(
            c_alias.b_id == B.id,
            c_alias.d_id == 1
        )
    )
```

This will produce the desired result, but makes for some pretty confusing SQL and is hard to  justify.

Comment: your example has some issues; you have an alias `c_alias`, but an unbound free variable `c` (not `C`, in caps).  Your expected sql also has some issues, `c` is mentioned twice, with the second having an alias in a syntactically invalid spot, (it the table alias immediately follows the table name, not the `on` clause).  Please provide valid python and working sql.

Comment: Thanks for being pedantic.  I've fixed the typos.

Comment: And `c` should be mentioned twice.  It is being selected as a Cartesian product with `a` and `b` while a where condition (not shown) is applied to `c_alias`.